# How to check if an array contains a specific number of values?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountVowel{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Getting the size of the array:

```
        System.out.println("Type how many words will be typed: ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
```

Filling array with string values

```
        String[] ar1 = new String[input];
        for(int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Type the elements of array with words: ");
            ar1[i] = scan.next();      
        }
```

Output of the program :

```
        System.out.println( input + " words are typed and " + 
        countVowels(ar1) + 
         " of them contain more than 3 vowels.");
    }
```

The method that counts vowels:

```
    public static int countVowels(String[] ar1){  // this method counts 

        int a = 0;
        String[] ar2 = new String[]{"a", "e", "i", "u", "y", "o"};
        for(int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++){
            for(String s : ar2){
                if(ar1[i].toLowerCase().contains(s)){
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

The method above is to check the vowels, but i dont know how to make it check if 
there are more than 3 vowels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int countVowels(String[] ar1) { // this method counts

    int vowelPerWord = 0;
    int totalWordsWithThreeVowels = 0;
    char[] ar2 = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'u', 'y', 'o' };
    for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
        vowelPerWord = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < ar1[i].length(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < ar2.length; k++) {
                if (ar2[k] == (ar1[i].charAt(j))) {
                    vowelPerWord++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (vowelPerWord >= 3) {
            totalWordsWithThreeVowels++;
        }
    }
    return totalWordsWithThreeVowels;
}
```

EDIT

alright now i fixed the error and edited the variablenames to make a bit more sense. although this is O(n*m) i believe (where n is the number of strings and m is the number of char the longest string has) (not so good complexity) it gets the job done ar1 in this case is your input of strings, ar2 are just the vowels that exist.

so you go through every string in ar1 and set "vowelPerWord" to 0, go through every single char in every string and check if it is a vowel increase the vowelPerWord by 1. at the end, after you went through every char of that string you check if there were 3 or more vowels, if so increase the totalWordsWithThreeVowels, which at the end is returned.

Comment: Please explain what this method does and maybe also clarify why you have 3 `for` loops and what exactly `a` and `b` do

Comment: hold on i am fixing an error in the above code right now

Comment: The extra loop will increase the complexity of code.

Comment: the third (most inner) loop is always gonna be O(6) so we can theoretically disregard it

Comment: Although the most inner loop is indeed only 6, if there are let's say 1000 words, the inner-most loop of 6 causes the iteration-count to go from 1,000,000 to 6,000,000.. The problem with nested loop, no matter how small, is that the complexity rises exponentially. This is currently complexity `O(6 * N^2)`, where `N` is the amount of words in `ar1`. PS: The vowel-loop of 6 indeed isn't really the issue here, it's the nested loop of two times the `ar1`.

Comment: yeah i know, i just gave the easiest to code solution, no weird looking regexes whatsoever, since the task looked more like a beginner type of task

Comment: @Alan I agree. Although I would personally also solve this with a Java 8 lambda and regex, for a beginner it's better to have a minor modification of the code they already have so they can learn from it. [I didn't use any regex in my answer either.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647713/1682559)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `replaceAll` method.
The main idea is to substract from `word.length()` the same word length without vowels. And check the difference.

```
public static int countVowels(String[] ar1){
    int a = 0;
    for (String word : ar1) {
        int i = word.length() - word.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[aeyiuo]", "").length();
        if (i >= 3) {
            a++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Or you can use `matches()` as @pkgajulapalli suggested. It can be quite concise with stream api:

```
long count = Arrays.stream(words)
        .filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().matches("(.*[aeyiuo].*){3,}"))
        .count();
```

Comment: Currently doesn't work with uppercase vowels, either use `s.toLowerCase()` or the regex group `[AaEeYyIiUuOo]`

Comment: Oh an for performance reasons you may want to use a predefined `Pattern` saved in a static variable or something and then use `pattern.matcher(s).replaceAll("")` :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an additional loop and count. Something like this:

```
// This method counts how many words have at least 3 vowels
public static int countVowels(String[] wordsArray){
  int atLeastThreeVowelsCount = 0;
  for(String word : wordsArray){
    int vowelCount = 0;
    for(String vowel : new String[]{ "a", "e", "i", "u", "y", "o" }){
      if(word.toLowerCase().contains(vowel)){
        vowelCount++;
      }
    }
    if(vowelCount >= 3){
      atLeastThreeVowelsCount++;
    }
  }
  return atLeastThreeVowelsCount;
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##fVNNj5swEL3zK0acQLRsq5V62HQrVXuqtD0l6mWVgzdMglOwI3tIiqL89nQGyGLSbC1ik/HMe/Px2Kq9@rgtfp/Put5ZR7BlQ96QrvL5ShmDbhZFu@a10itYVcp7@Km0OUbAazB7UsTH3uoCar5M5uS02bwsQbmNT3tfWQMgeD7hEQweLqZk3nrCOtcmnY3uvc02lO8YkCqTxIt2h1DaAxOZFg7WFR4OuqrgFYH4rniAOIDgKP7tGmI6Yc0N/qEfhpJ0Jtcj1Zjx50tmvamLXo6Ia@uSDpXdPs34@CoxeYVmQyX/z7KgYFl3d@/WQSUCVlijIQ92zUBOcVGayr6yaS2ymOpFL8NihkqCWk7/a@DQjQzioXnKDY0DZQq2ZhAQrmxj6Jc9YOUTpk67OE6UE6/50hBPG2orECWP9J41IL75Je1TFPUtgEWpPdRIpS16VH89xVLtERRBhcrTG9QNnUn3w8TeZtfhfJcepseOlP4lnShD0bOQLUqH2IM9iVc32cnAe4qOAB4mPEGzBLFL@gbIBKZzYpxAZcsjxCr@ADHKpmVrZGtlszGcrkSl14lkkZN9ZjD3pDwmaT5MxCcdQ3oVA0F2WTbV1Sm6/c48QUnfHuE@nerxdgdD@BHOITXOvBdzUczpfP4SiVwiflRE6CmSWuWzELkMumC1tkjKWNaiswb/Ag)

Note that I've also given the variables some more useful names, instead of `ar1`, `s`, etc. so it's easier to read what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex matching to find if a string contains any set of characters. For example, if you want to find if a string contains any of vowels, you can use:

```
String str = "yydyrf";
boolean contains = str.toLowerCase().matches(".*[aeiou].*");
System.out.println(contains);
```

**EDIT:**

So your code would look like:

```
public static int countVowels(String[] ar1) {
    int a = 0;
    String[] ar2 = new String[] { "a", "e", "i", "u", "y", "o" };
    String pattern = ".*[" + String.join("", ar2) + "].*";
    for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
        if (ar1[i].matches(pattern)) {
            a++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Although that's indeed an easier way than the loop and contains, it doesn't answer OP's question..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public static int countVowels(String[] words) {
    char[] chars = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'u', 'y', 'o'};
    int wordsWith3Vowels = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        int countedVowels = 0;
        for (char s : chars) {
            if (word.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) != -1) {
                countedVowels++;
            }
        }
        if (countedVowels >= 3) {
            wordsWith3Vowels++;
        }
    }
    return wordsWith3Vowels;
}
```

Which uses `char`s instead of `String`s which is a tad faster

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int countVowels(String[] ar1){  // this method counts 
    //Create hash map key = array string && value = vowels count 
    Map<String,Integer> mapVowels=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    int a = 0;
    String[] ar2 = new String[]{"a", "e", "i", "u", "y", "o"};
    for(int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++){
        for(String s : ar2){
            if(ar1[i].toLowerCase().contains(s)){
                //Check map string already has vowel count then increase by one
                if(mapVowels.get(s)!=null) {
                 mapVowels.put(s,mapVowels.get(s)+1);
                 //After add the vowels count get actual count and check is it more than 3
                 if(mapVowels.get(s)>3)
                     a++;
                }
                else {
                    //If the vowels string new for map then add vowel count as 1 for first time
                    mapVowels.put(s,1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since `java-8` you can now use Streams.

```
String[] values = {"AA","BC","CD","AE"};
```

boolean contains = Arrays.stream(values).anyMatch("s"::equals);

To check whether an array of `int`, `double` or `long` contains a `value` use `IntStream`, `DoubleStream` or `LongStream` respectively.

Example
int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
boolean contains = IntStream.of(a).anyMatch(x -> x == 4);